# Shell NameSpace changes label of every mapped network drive

Tags: powershell, user-interface, networking, label, drive

I'm working on a GUI script that would map a network share as a drive.
So far I was succesful, but now, every time I map another drive it's name is applied to each previously created one. Please help. I want the drives to each have a separate name

```
$button_click_2 = { $letter = -join($textBox.Text,":")
                    Invoke-Expression "C:\Windows\System32\net.exe use $letter \\192.168.0.10\GRY /persistent:yes"            
                    $shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
                    $shell.NameSpace("$letter").Self.Name = $textBox2.Text
                    }

$textBox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBox2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,70) ### Location of the text box
$textBox2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(240, 20) ### Size of the text box
$textBox2.Multiline = $true ### Allows multiple lines of data


$textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
$textBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(240,20)
$form.Controls.Add($textBox)

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'Test Przycisku Skrot' ### Text to be displayed in the title
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,500) ### Size of the window
$form.StartPosition = 'Manual'
$form.Location      = '10,10'
$form.Topmost = $true  ### Optional - Opens on top of other windows


$test_button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$test_button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,420)
$test_button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (170,23)
$test_button.Text = "Mapowanie Dysku Sieciowego"
$test_button.Add_Click($button_click_2)

$form.Controls.AddRange(@($test_button,$textBox,$textBox2))



$form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: [1] it looks like you are assigning multiple drive maps to the same target ... what happens when you do that manually? does it apply the same name to all mapped drives that point to the same share? ///// SHY are you using `net.exe` and `shell.application` instead of `New-PSDrive`? the `-Name` would be the letter & the `-Description` would be the drive label.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey - `NET USE` will retain the mapping outside PowerShell; `New-PSDrive` assignments go away as soon as the PowerShell session does.

Comment: Re [1] that is true. For the purpose of testing the script I "shared" a single folder. I have not yet gotten around to introducing third textbox where a new variable "path" will be entered.
Re [the other part] I want the drives to persist. If I use that parameter name must be given as a plain letter (i.e. V or K) instead of variable, hence net.exe where variables are accepted.

I have written batch script that does exactly that. But I decided I want it to look nice. Instead of DOS prompt window.

Comment: Below you can see the results of both PS script and batch script respectively
[url=https://ibb.co/p2PkMLS][img]https://i.ibb.co/9nvd1r7/1.jpg[/img][/url]
[url=https://ibb.co/z2FC8sj][img]https://i.ibb.co/vdhfs1g/2.jpg[/img][/url]

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - have you read the help for that cmdlet? you can make them stick if you use the clearly documented parameters. [*grin*]

Comment: @Nawad-samagamb - [1 & 2] take a look at the parameters & the help for the `New-PSDrive` cmdlet. it can be persistent if you use the parameters as listed in the help for that cmdlet. [*grin*] ///// [3] your image links do not work at this time.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey - I know it can be persistent. What I want is to use variable as drive letter which i cannot do. Quote from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive?view=powershell-7.1

-Name
Specifies a name for the new drive. For persistent mapped network drives, use a drive letter. For temporary PowerShell drives, you aren't limited to drive letters, use any valid string.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey - That only works if you dotsource the script; you can't persist it from e.g., a script cmdlet/advanced function in a module.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - it should work in the situation mentioned in this Question.

Comment: @Nawad-samagamb - perhaps i am totally misunderstanding you ... but this >>> `Get-Help New-PSDrive -Parameter name` <<< just mentions that you can use a drive letter ... you can use a _variable_ to hold that drive letter. you can use `Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | Where-Object Root -Match ':'` to get the in-use drive letters, derive the available letters, and then pass the one you want to `New-PSDrive` in a $Var ... and make it persist if wanted.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey The issue is, that everytime I use a variable in New-PSDrive PS throws up an error, does not matter if I define it myself or if it's taken from textbox. Nontheless I will take a look at the help topic you mentioned.

Comment: @Nawad-samagamb - what is the exact error you get? i suspect the problem is the content of the $Var, not that it _is_ a $Var. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that if you even if you map a shared folder under multiple drive letters, the still is a single registry key in MountingPoints2 that hold the Label.